# Screen video recording at Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, avfoundation, screen-recording

I'm working with AVFoundation to record screen or part of screen.
Here 2 code samples for which i work.

1.http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AVScreenShack/Listings/AVScreenShack_AVScreenShackDocument_m.html

2.http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1740/_index.html

Simple fullscreen recording or recording with cropping rect just fine,
but when i'm trying to change rect while recording, i'm getting error:

> Did finish recording to file://localhost/Users/Shared/screenMovie.mp4
>   due to error Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11806
>   "Recording Stopped" UserInfo=0x13a07f9e0
>   {AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=true,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Recording Stopped,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try recording again.}

Apple documentation says about error with code -11806:

> AVErrorSessionConfigurationChanged Recording stopped because the
>   configuration of media sources and destinations changed.

I can't find any info in docs about it.
i have suggestion, that i can't change rect while recording. But at the same time i can't find any proof about it.

Comment: i'm just trying to change origin coordinates, not size of the rect. I think it can help. Here's some my code to changing coords of recording frame: http://pastebin.com/XGaTM55f

Answer (score 2):

When you change the rect while recording, the recording format changes and it can't continue to record to same output. However, you can continue recording to a new file.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error {

// Check for error
// If an error occurred and AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey is YES, then
// start recording to a new file here

}
```

Comment: but when you dragging the window, it will create about 10-15 files per second - and all of them will be corrupted. I'm just disable drag option.

Comment: Maybe you're not capturing the right thing... I mean, Maybe you need to capture the window, and not the screen (with translation and cropping) ? How did you finally get this to work?